# i am using prey source code to make own app but it comes to error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

well i am using prey source code to develop my own anti theft app. according to git , i got 5 files from there.. but i am working on master one, i think thats correct one.

when i uploaded it to eclipse i get 100 error, out of which one is still remaining in the 
**FileConfigReader.java** the error is :

Description: **config** cannot be resolved or is not a field
Resource:  FileConfigReader.java
Path:  /LoginActivity/src/com/prey
Location: line 25
Type:  Java Problem

the line where error is coming :

> InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config);

the code of that file :

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Created by Carlos Yaconi
 * Copyright 2012 Fork Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * License: GPLv3
 * Full license at "/LICENSE"
 ******************************************************************************/
package com.prey;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;

public class FileConfigReader {

    private static FileConfigReader _instance = null;
    Properties properties;

    private FileConfigReader(Context ctx) {
        try {
            PreyLogger.d("Loading config properties from file...");
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config);
            properties.load(is);
            is.close();
            PreyLogger.d("Config: "+properties);

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            PreyLogger.e("Config file wasn't found", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             PreyLogger.e("Couldn't read config file", e);
        }
    }

    public static FileConfigReader getInstance(Context ctx){
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new FileConfigReader(ctx);
        return _instance;

    }

    public String getAgreementId(){
        return properties.getProperty("agreement-id");
    }
    public String getGcmId(){
        return properties.getProperty("gcm-id");
    }
    public String getGcmIdPrefix(){
        return properties.getProperty("gcm-id-prefix");
    }

    public String getc2dmAction(){
        return properties.getProperty("c2dm-action");
    }
    public String getc2dmMessageSync(){
        return properties.getProperty("c2dm-message-sync");
    }

    public String getPreyDomain(){
        return properties.getProperty("prey-domain");
    }

    public String getPreySubdomain(){
        return properties.getProperty("prey-subdomain");
    }

    public String getPreyUiSubdomain(){
        return properties.getProperty("prey-ui-subdomain");
    }

    public String getPreyMinorVersion(){
        return properties.getProperty("prey-minor-version");
    }

    public boolean isAskForPassword() {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty("ask-for-password"));
    }
    public boolean isLogEnabled() {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty("log-enabled"));
    }

    public String getAnalyticsUA() {
        return properties.getProperty("analytics-ua");
    }

}
```

any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you create the resource "config"?

This resource must be available in the system, the same way as the other resources (layouts, strings etc.)

Check this guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Your file "config" should be in the res/raw folder.

Comment: can you provide me code to do that.. i can't understand what it seriously need to be done.. :(

Comment: I am not talking about the file you posted, you should read all the guides on developer.android.com and the link I provided before.
You will find lots of examples of what you are trying to do also on this website.